# displaying grid of images in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with a column containing 495 rows of URLs. I want to display these URLs in jupyter notebook as a grid of images. The first row of the dataframe is shown here. Any help is appreciated.

```
id           latitude     longitude     owner             title                          url
23969985288 37.721238   -123.071023 7679729@N07 There she blows!    https://farm5.staticflickr.com/4491/2396998528...
```

I have tried the following way,

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
for index, row in data1.iterrows():
  display(HTML("<img src='%s'>"%(i["url"])))
```

However, running of above code displays message

```
> TypeError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-4c2081563c17> in <module>()
      1 from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
      2 for index, row in data1.iterrows():
----> 3   display(HTML("<img src='%s'>"%(i["url"])))

TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Please add some code that shows what you've already tried.

Comment: Hi, I have added the some details

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way to show a grid of images in the Jupyter notebook is probably using `matplotlib` to create the grid, since you can also plot images on `matplotlib` axes using `imshow`.

I'm using a 3x165 grid, since that is 495 exactly. Feel free to mess around with that to change the dimensions of the grid.

```
import urllib
f, axarr = plt.subplots(3, 165)
curr_row = 0
for index, row in data1.iterrows():
     # fetch the url as a file type object, then read the image
     f = urllib.request.urlopen(row["url"])
     a = plt.imread(f)

     # find the column by taking the current index modulo 3
     col = index % 3
     # plot on relevant subplot
     axarr[col,curr_row].imshow(a)
     if col == 2:
         # we have finished the current row, so increment row counter
         curr_row += 1
```

Answer (score 23):

Your idea of using `IPython.core.display` with HTML is imho the best approach for that kind of task. `matplotlib` is super inefficient when it comes to plotting such a huge number of images (especially if you have them as URLs).
There's a small package I built based on that concept - it's called [ipyplot](https://github.com/karolzak/ipyplot)

```py
import ipyplot

images = data1['url'].values
labels = data1['id'].values

ipyplot.plot_images(images, labels, img_width=150)
```

You would get a plot similar to this:
[image]

Comment: Would be nice if this would work with GeoTIFF images. Something like integrating https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio eventually.

Answer (score 1):

I found a small matplotlib method easier than ipyplot, which has a number of opinionated decisions (borders around images, titles, "show html"-text) that I did not like.

```py
def image_grid(imgs: List[Path]):
    """Load and show images in a grid from a list of paths"""
    count = len(imgs)
    plt.figure(figsize=(11, 18))
    for ix, path in enumerate(imgs):
        i = Image.open(path)
        resize = (150, 150)
        i = i.resize(resize)
        plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3, right=0.8, top=0.5)
        ax = plt.subplot(3, 5, ix + 1)
        ax.axis('off')
        plt.imshow(i)
```

Then:

```py
imgs = list((OUTPUT / "images").glob(f'name*'))
image_grid(imgs)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code below to your cell:

```
display(IPython.display.HTML('''
  <flexthis></flexthis>
  <style> div.jp-Cell-outputArea:has(flexthis) {
    display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
  }</style>
'''))
```

and then, on the same cell, use calls to `IPython.display.Image` or anything else you want to show.

---

This code above allows you to add custom CSS to that specific output cell. I'm using a flex box (display:flex), but you can change it to your liking.

Answer (score -2):

I can only do it by "brute force":

However, I only manage to do it manually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

%matplotlib inline

img1=mpimg.imread('Variable_8.png')
img2=mpimg.imread('Variable_17.png')
img3=mpimg.imread('Variable_18.png')
          ...

fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4,ax5,ax6)) = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True) 

ax1.imshow(img1)
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.imshow(img2)
ax2.axis('off')
   ....
```

Do not know if ot helps

Comment: I was just asking the same as you. Asking for help to get an elegant way to do it :/

Comment: Check also the answer of @Benares at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55981902/6177877