# Display list of Python PIL.Image.Image as grid of images in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

I have a Python list of PIL.Image.Image objects called `all_images` like so:

```
[<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=192x256 at 0x10855CF8>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=192x256 at 0x1053AE10>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=192x256 at 0x106445C0>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=192x256 at 0x10644E48>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=192x256 at 0x10644BE0>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=192x256 at 0x10644C18>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=192x256 at 0x106447F0>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=192x256 at 0x146D32B0>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=192x256 at 0x146D37F0>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=192x256 at 0x146D3EB8>,
 <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=192x256 at 0x146D3668>]
```

I would like to display them all in a nice-looking grid as in this [tutorial](https://rock-it.pl/images-augmentation-for-deep-learning-with-keras/). In the tutorial he just saves the images to disk; I would like to display them in a Jupyter Notebook.

When I do `Image.open(all_images[0])` it's opening up in Photoshop for some reason. I also tried

```
from IPython.display import Image 
Image(all_images[0])
```

but `PIL.Image.Image` is an invalid input.

Comment: Do you want to save the grid of images, or *just* display them?

Comment: Just display them

Comment: I know `matplotlib` works with displaying images in Jupyter Notebook. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508168/displaying-grid-of-images-in-jupyter-notebook) another StackOverflow post that might help you out to use that package.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [IPyPlot package](https://github.com/karolzak/ipyplot) to save some hustle.
With IPyPlot you can display images (numpy.arrays, PIL objects or simply URIs) with something as simple as this:

```py
import ipyplot

ipyplot.plot_images(images_list)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need help maintaining it? there are PR still open since 2021

Comment: @ricoms help is always welcomed! Let's get it touch

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create your own grid of `Image` objects, save it as a `.png` or `.jpeg`/`.jpg`, then display it using another package.

Using `PIL`, you can create a new `Image` object and paste the individual `Image` objects onto it. For instance, say you want a 4x4 grid. You create a new `Image` of `width=4*width_of_smaller_image` and `height=4*height_of_smaller_image`. Then, looping over the appropriate pixels locations, [paste](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste) from `all_images` onto it.

Comment: If this intrigues you, let me know and I can provide some sample code.