# Grid of images using a loop in Jupyter-Notebook. How?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, grid, jupyter-notebook

I want to show images `var_1.png,...,var_40.png` in a 2x3 matrix format inside a Jupyter Notebook.
[image]
However, I only manage to do it manually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

%matplotlib inline

img1=mpimg.imread('Variable_8.png')
img2=mpimg.imread('Variable_17.png')
img3=mpimg.imread('Variable_18.png')
          ...

fig, ((ax1, ax2, ax3), (ax4,ax5,ax6)) = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True) 

ax1.imshow(img1)
ax1.axis('off')
ax2.imshow(img2)
ax2.axis('off')
   ....
```

I want something cleaner. Something like a list comprehension that specifies

```
image=[img(i)=mpimg.imread('Variable_(i).png') for i in [8,17,28, ..]

[ax[j].imshow(img(j)),ax[j].axis('off') for j in range(len(image))]
```

Some help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehensions quickly become unreadable if there is more than one thing they do. Also it appears it is considered bad style to use list comprehensions if the content of the list is not actually used at all.

Hence I would propose the following

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

images = [plt.imread(f"Variable_{i}.png") for i in [8,17,28,29,31,35]]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True) 

for img, ax in zip(images, axes.flat):
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.axis('off')
```

Comment: Even, a dummy like me understood you post :D  // Dorian. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
imgs_names = ...
imgs = [mpimg.imread(name) for name in imgs_names]

n_rows = 2
n_cols = 3
fig, axes = subplots(n_rows, n_cols)

[(axes[i][j].imshow(imgs[i*n_cols + j]), axes[i][j].axis('off')) for i in range(n_rows) for j in range(n_cols)]
```

?

Rmk: this does not work if `n_cols=1` or `n_rows=1`, because `axes` is then a list, not an array.

Comment: Thank you so much. If, you do not mind can I make a new post summarizing and writing it so dummies as me can understand?. You have answer so quickly that you missed to write  the `plt.` in `plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols) of ` line `6`